# How can I find out an induced subgraph of k nodes with at least m*k*(k-1)/n*(n-1) edges

Tags: algorithm, greedy, subgraph

I am required to use a greedy algorithm to resolve this problem (here `m` is the number of edges and `n` is the number of vertices in the original graph). Intuitively， I know it is somehow about density of graph (due to `m/n*(n-1)` part), so I try to use greedy algorithm to remove the vertex with minimum degree each iteration until I get a `k` nodes graph, but I don't know how can I GARUNTEE the algorithm give me the final graph with at least `m*k*(k-1)/n*(n-1)`  edges.

Looking for any hints, Thanks.

Comment: How many edges is the graph guaranteed to contain after one removal? Use induction.

Comment: There should be at least `m-n` remaining edges and `n-1` remaining vertices; in the second step there should be at least `m-n-(n-1)` remaining edges and `n-2` vertices; unfortunately, there is no pen and paper within reach...

Comment: The node which is removed in the `k'`-th step has a degree of at most `n-k'`, i.e. the degree of the removed node gets smaller.

Comment: I don't understand yet how the minimality of the degree of the chosen node relates to the graph's density.

Comment: @Codor Averaging argument.

Comment: Yes, I was guessing and reading [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dense_graph).

Comment: The minimum degree is at most `2m/n` by `sum of degrees = 2m` and that averaging argument, is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

Let's define the density of a graph `p=m/(n*(n-1))` (for undirected graph it should be `p=2*m/(n*(n-1))`. Note that for a graph with density `p` and `k` vertices, it has `(k*(k-1)) * p` edges. Also note that when you greedily remove a vertex with the minimum degree, it won't decrease the density of the graph (will proof it below). So when you get the subgraph with `k` vertices, its density is equal to or greater than `m/(n*(n-1))`, then the subgraph contains at least `k*(k-1)(m*/n*(n-1))` edges.

Let G be a graph with `m` edges and `n` vertices, then `p=m/n`. Let `d` the minimum degree of all vertices. then we have `n * d <= m` i.e., `d <= m/n`. So when you remove the vertex with the minimum degree, you get a graph with `m-d` edges and `n-1` vertices, then the density of the new graph will be `p'=(m-d)/(n-1) >= (m-m/n)/(n-1) = m/n = p`. So we have that the greedy algorithm won't decrease the density of a graph.

Comment: Great, Thanks. I got a more accurate induction from your solution. p' = (m-d)/n(n-1)>= (m-2m/n)/(n-1)(n-2) = m/n(n-1) = p.